# 2 filter dsl query looks the same and how to combine

Tags: kibana, querydsl

In Kibana I created 2 filters:
raw.browserJs.isWebDriver is true and raw.browserJs.isWebDriver isnot true. why the edit query DSL is the same for both:

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "raw.browserJs.isWebDriver": {
        "query": true,
        "type": "phrase"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Also, how can i add condition in order to have one large DSL query with:

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "appName": {
        "query": "temp",
        "type": "phrase"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The query DSL showing in Kibana is not the actual query which is send to elasticsearch. A range filter for the selected period is added and filters are inverted. You can see the actual query in the underlying request that is send in your browser.

You filter where raw.browserJs.isWebDriver is not true will end up in something like:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must_not": [
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "raw.browserJs.isWebDriver": true
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

You can combine multiple conditions in one DSL query with the bool query.(https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html)

The following query will work in your example:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "raw.browserJs.isWebDriver": true
          }
        },
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "appName": "temp"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```